# my game sound will work on computer but not on ipad or iphone

Tags: iphone, audio, ipad, game-development, html5-audio

I have written a game which requires sounds to be produced when an answer is given via drag & drop. The wave files are (both on my host server)
var sound1 = ec_alert5.wav') and
var sound2 = fart%20noise.wav')
The call is
sound1.play() or
sound2.play();.
It works fine on the computer but will not work on an ipad or iphone.
Thx for your help.
Walt Sautter

I tried all suggestions found on the Internet.None have worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: WebAudio can be a little funny. Check to see if the mute switch on your iPhone is turned on. Since the audio requires an interaction to play, I would also recommend using a framework like [p5.js](https://p5js.org) to stop you having to reinvent the wheel

Comment: Here is the code to load the sound and then play it:   var sound1 = new Audio('http://wsautter.com/MATHLY%20HIGH%20LOW/ec_alert5.mp3'); 
  var sound2 = new Audio('http://wsautter.com/MATHLY%20HIGH%20LOW/fart%20noise.mp3');
   if (bb == nmbb){
    
     sound1.play();   
   }
   else
   {   
     sound2.play();
    alert('Wrong - Move to a different positon');
    
   }

Comment: I would definitely take the [p5 sound file](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.SoundFile) approach in this case. Also, you may be best putting a short working version in the body of the question. Sadly, comments don't allow you to easily post code.